# iOS UISplitViewController - hide master view pane with smooth transition

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, transition

I'm working on an iPad app with the UISplitViewController.  I've managed to add a button on the detail view navigation bar to 'maximise' the detail pane in landscape mode by hiding the master view (like Dropbox does).  I did this by setting the split view controller delegate to nil and then back to it's delegate in order to force 'shouldHideViewController' to fire.  This works but there's no transition - it just flicks to full screen.  I'd like the view to stretch across the screen in a transition (as Dropbox does).

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: You might have added  the UISplitViewcontroller manually.If you use the one provided by apple during project creation you won't have to face such issues....just a suggestion.